# Remove doesn't work in cloned object

Tags: jquery, clone

Remove objects in this code works fine in jquery 1.5, but doesn't work with jquery 1.6:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>.content {border: 1px solid #333;} .delete {color: red;}</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="master">
<div class="content">Some content <span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
</div>
<div class="clone">Clone</div>
<script>
    $(".clone").click(function () {
        $("#master").find(".content").last().clone().appendTo("#master");
    });

    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $(this).parents(".content").remove();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With  Jquery 1.6+ I can remove just first element. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with `clone()` in [1.5.0 that was fixed in 1.5.1](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) regarding the optional `withDataAndEvents` parameter.

From the documentation:

> In jQuery 1.5.0 the default value was incorrectly true; it was changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.

Your code should thus be:

```
$(".clone").click(function () {
    $("#master").find(".content").last().clone(true).appendTo("#master");
});

$(".delete").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".content").remove();
});
```